# Truth functions and truth table

Tags: logic

I am trouble with the following question:

"The connective “unless” can be ambiguous, and this exercise will pinpoint
the ambiguity.
We awake at dawn, and we are told
We will have a picnic today unless it is raining at 10 A.M.
Let $P$ be "We will have a picnic today" and Q be "it is raining at 10 A.M." $P$u $Q$ denote “P unless Q.” (This is not a standard notation.) Complete
as much of a truth table as possible for PuQ, and discuss any ambiguous
lines.

**My attempt** 
$$\begin{array} {|c|}
\hline
P & Q & PuQ& \\ \hline
F & T & T&  \\ \hline
T & F & T \\ \hline
T & T & F \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: I can't even understand what it means for a connective to be ambiguous.

Comment: @GitGud I think you can think of a connective as ambiguous if you can't know what truth value it will take on.

Comment: @GitGud - the natural language **is** ambiguous. Thus, we have some "fuzzyness" in translating "unless" with a truth-functional connective which, "by construction", cannot be ambiguous.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I see, they meant the natural language connective, not the logical one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the discussion in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614481/the-translations-of-unless-and-except-into-symbolic-logic) and the extract from Stephen Cole Kleene, [Mathematical logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486425339) (1967 - Dover ed  2002).

According to his proposal [page 64] :

> > $A \lor B$ is $A$ unless $B$ [usually] and is $A$ except when $B$ [usually].

An "informal" argument in support of this "translation" is the following.

We can rewrite our "P *unless* Q" :

> "We will have a picnic today" *unless* "it is raining at 10 A.M."

as :

> if "it is **not** raining at 10 A.M.", then "we will have a picnic today".

But this is "if **not** Q, then P", which in the truth-functional model is equivalent to :

> > $Q \lor P$.

But **there is** an *ambiguity* in "translating" from the natural language into the truth-functional model, as referred in the question.

If we decide for XOR, we have to leave the "equivalence" of "P unless Q" with "if not Q, then P".

I agree with StumpyLeg's answer; three case are "clear-cut". The doubt is with the $T-T$ case: here lies the choice between OR and XOR.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Indeed, for some reason, "if not Q then P" sounds more intuitive than does $Q\lor P$ but as you note, they are truth-functionally equivalent.

Comment: @amWhy - YES. **I think** that "we logician" (sorry for this ...) are accustomed to "blame" $\rightarrow$, but in fact we have some problem also with $\lor$ (see *intuitionsitic* logic). Of course the problem is "trivial": it is the problem of mapping a "fuzzy" world (natural language with nuances) into a "bi-valent" model. But in many cases it works !

Comment: It is rather interesting  that we use it as XOR in most cases. So it is not that obvious.

Answer (score 1):

$P$, $Q$ both false is clear-cut: $P u Q$ is false. (If there's no rain and no picnic, the announcement was erroneous.) If there's any ambiguity, it's the T/T case (last line in the OP's table). It comes down to whether "unless" should be read as OR (then the statement is true) or as XOR (then it's false). That seems to be the intent of the example, since rain would normally nix a picnic but the announcement doesn't explicitly commit to cancellation in case of rain.

Comment: So how would one know what is explicit "enough"?

Comment: One can't always expect a hard-and-fast rule for how to interpret natural language and translate it into a formalism like truth-functional logic. (You can always *make up* hard-and-fast rules, but that's not what you're asking.) However, if someone were to say, "We'll have a picnic unless it's raining at 10 A.M.--in which case we may or may not, depending on how bad it is," then that's OR. Whereas "We'll have a picnic unless it's raining at 10 A.M., in which case we'll stay inside" means XOR.

Answer (score 1):

One might be tempted to say that "$P$ unless $Q$" is the same as "if not $Q$, then $P$". In fact this is also the semantic used e.g. in PERL, which seems to be the only programming language that allows `if $condition then functioncall();` to be written as `functioncall() unless !$condition;`.

But in natural language the use may vary. For example, "We'll go to the movies unless it rains" may be interpreted differenetly than "If it doesn't rain, we'll go to the movies". The former seems to suggest much more strongly that also "If it rains then we do not go to the movies" holds.

Answer (score 1):

unless = if not

P unless Q = P if not Q

I think?