# Writing statements using logical connectives.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, logic-translation

Can someone please check whether my solutions are okay? I felt a little confused with some.

> If Mr. Jones is happy, Mrs. Jones is not happy, and if Mr. Jones is not happy, Mrs. Jones is not happy.

$p$: Mr. Jones is happy.

$q$: Mrs. Jones is happy.

$(p\to \neg q)\wedge (\neg p \to \neg q)$

> Either Sam will come to the party and Max will not, or Sam will not come to the party and Max will enjoy himself.

$p$: Sam will come to the party.

$q$: Max will come to the party.

$r$: Max will enjoy himself.

$(p \vee \neg q) \vee (\neg p \wedge r)$

(I do not know what it means by "and Max will not" so I assumed statement $q$.)

> A sufficient condition for $x$ to be odd is that $x$ is prime.

$p$: $x$ is odd.

$q$: $x$ is prime.

$q\to p$

> A necessary condition for a sequence $s$ to converge is that $s$ be bounded.

$p$: The sequence $s$ converges.

$q$: The sequence $s$ is bounded.

$p\to q$

> A necessary and sufficient condition for the sheikh to be happy is that he has wine, women, and song.

$p$: The sheikh is happy.

$q$: The sheikh has wine, women, and song.

$p\leftrightarrow  q$

> Karpov will win the chess tournament unless Kasparov wins today.

$p$: Karpov will win the chess tournament.

$q$: Kasparov wins today.

$p\leftrightarrow \neg q$

(I do not understand the logic for "unless".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally your statements are OK, there are just few errors.

> Either Sam will come to the party and Max will not, or Sam will not come to the party and Max will enjoy himself.

$(p \land \lnot q) \lor (\lnot p \land r)$, and not $(p \lor \lnot q) \lor (\lnot p \land r)$ (I guess you just made a typo), where:

$p$: Sam will come to the party;

$q$: Max will come to the party;

$r$: Max will enjoy himself.

> A necessary and sufficient condition for the sheikh to be happy is that he has wine, women, and song.

$p \leftrightarrow (q \land r \land s)$, where:

$p$: The sheikh is happy;

$q$: The sheikh has wine;

$r$: The sheikh has women;

$s$: The sheikh has song.

> Karpov will win the chess tournament unless Kasparov wins today.

$\lnot q \to p$, or equivalently $p \lor q$, and not $p \leftrightarrow \lnot q$, where:

$p$: Karpov will win the chess tournament;

$q$: Kasparov wins today.

Someones prefer to translate "unless" by $\leftrightarrow$, but I prefer the translation given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614481/the-translations-of-unless-and-except-into-symbolic-logic).

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time in correcting my mistakes and letting me know what I did wrong. Some of them I definitely guessed!