# Translating "None of the paintings is valuable except the battle pieces."

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

**Example 1:**

> No intelligent person who drinks to excess also eats to excess.

I am stuck on deciding whether this means

**a)** $\forall x(Ix \implies -(Dx \lor Ex)$

or

**b)** $\forall x(Ix \land Dx \implies -Ex).$

**Example 2:**

> None of the paintings is valuable except the battle pieces.

I think that what this is saying (using intuition) is that, if you give me a Painting then it is not Valuable unless you give me a Battle piece in which case it is Valuable; thus, in symbols:

**c)** $\forall x(Px \implies -Vx) \lor \forall x(Bx \implies Vx).$

Alternatively, it could be closer to Example 1; thus, in symbols:

**d)** $\forall x(Px \implies -(Vx \lor Bx)).$

Or I could very well be out to lunch on all of these translations.

Comment: Example 1: second one; equivalently: $\lnot \exists x (Ix \land Dx \land Ex)$

Comment: In the second example your (d) version is almost correct. It is saying that any painting is either not valuable or else a battle painting and valuable (as you said), so we could write it as $\forall x (Px \implies (\neg Vx \vee (Vx \wedge Bx))$. But now $\vee$ distributes over $\wedge$ so that becomes $(\neg Vx \vee Vx)\wedge (\neg Vx \vee Bx)$ which is $\neg Vx \vee Bx$.

Comment: Jeez, my c) option was out to lunch, I felt so confident about it too!

Comment: @thebogatron The parenthetical "as you said" in your comment is wrong: your translation does not actually correspond to what the OP said ("What this is saying (using intuition) is that, if you give me a Painting then it is not Valuable unless you give me a Battle piece in which case it is Valuable"), but to my answer's Suggestion (2) below. $\quad$ Since the word 'except' is slightly ambiguous, especially in technical writing, it should probably be used judiciously.

Answer (score 1):

> **Example 2:**
>
> > None of the paintings is valuable except the battle pieces.
>
> I think that what this is saying (using intuition) is that, if you
> give me a Painting then it is not Valuable unless you give me a Battle
> piece in which case it is Valuable; thus, in symbols:

I agree, so: $$\forall x\big(Px\to(Vx\leftrightarrow Bx)\big).\tag1$$

However, there is [another](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2926040/21813) interpretation of the word 'except': $$\forall x\big(Px\to(Vx\to Bx)\big).\tag2$$

1. *Everyone **except** Sue attended the event.*

   Sue did not attend the event.
2. *I won't take an umbrealla, **except** when it rains.*

   When it rains, I may still not take an umbrella.

> **Example 1:**
>
> > No intelligent person who drinks to excess also eats to excess.
>
> **a)** $\forall x(Ix \implies -(Dx \lor Ex)$

a) *No* (intelligent person) *who* (drinks to excess *also* eats to excess)

> **b)** $\forall x(Ix \land Dx \implies -Ex).$

b) *No* (intelligent person *who* drinks to excess) *also* (eats to excess)

Option B is correct because the given sentence doesn't assert anything about moderate drinkers who are intelligent.

Notice that Option B has the categorical structure "No X is Y", whereas forcing Option A to correspond to the natural-language sentence results in the verbal connectives being illogically placed.

For completeness, Mauro's translation: $\lnot \exists x (Ix \land Dx \land Ex);$ note that some (not me) may judge this to be logically equivalent to a translation rather than actually a translation.